# faster algo for pow(x,y,m) in python, when x = 2 is fix. (Factor-testing on Mersenne Primes)

Tags: python

I´m searching for a faster algo for `pow(x,y,m)` in python, when `x = 2` is fixed. `y`, the Exponent, is a definetly prime. first `m` is `2*y + 1`   and grows for amount of `2 * y * 4620`. Any Idea ? The code
below seems not to be slower than the original and  I believe, that this is the original way python does. Is there a way to speed up this, when `x` is always 2 ?

```
def pow_mod(x, y, z):
    number = 1
    while y:
        if y & 1:
            number = number * x % z
        y >>= 1
        x = x*x % z        
    return number
```

I need a funktion like this:

```
def test_factor(exponent,factor):
if "factor is possible":               # here must be a code I search for
    if pow(2,exponent,factor) == 1:    # so it must be tested
        return True
    else: 
        return False
else:                                  # so the built in pow funktion
    return False                       # is not used
```

Comment: Python's inbuilt pow function supports modular exponentiation and is very fast

Comment: *"I believe, that this is the original way python does"* that's quite an assumption - here's the source code for it: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/036fe85bd3e6cd01093d836d71792a1966f961e8/Objects/longobject.c#L4244

Comment: is Z in pow( x,y, z) always a mersenne prime? If so I can provide you with a much faster algorithm than pythons builtin pow